# React Navigation: best way to implement logout navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, stack-navigator

I'm using `react-navigation@4.0.10` in my React Native app, and have a `Login` screen and two `TabNavigator` screens. Logging in from the `Login` screen takes me to `TabNavigator_1`, and if I log out from `TabNavigator_1` I just use `this.props.navigation.goBack()`. The problem is, to get to `TabNavigator_2` I click a button in `TabNavigator_1` which triggers `this.props.navigation.navigate('TabNavigator_2')`, so `TabNavigator_2` is now on top of the stack, and calling `this.props.navigation.goBack()` would just take me back to `TabNavigator_1` instead of `Login`.

What's the best way to approach this, so that clicking `Log out` from `TabNavigator_1` and `TabNavigator_2` takes me back to `Login`?

Comment: can you post code of your navigation screen?

Comment: usually people set up auth/unauth switch nav as their root. so `Login` would be one and your tab navigator would be the other. when a use logs out you just switch back to `Login`

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

to go back to login screen is pretty bad pattern to me.

**Pattern I recommend:**

1) After successfull login, you store logged-in user(only id and essentials credentials) in your asyncstorage.

2)After pressing Logout Button, you clear that credentials from asyncStorage.

**In your Initial screeen**

Check if there is logged-in user info inside asyncStorage

> If yes   ->   got to tabNavigator screen
>
> else     ->   go to login screen

**Rough Demo**

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  {isLoggedIn ? (

    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigator} />

  ) : (
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={LogInScreen} />
  )}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: I took this approach and the problem is there is no animation after logging out. (Because no navigation event is fired).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")
```

Based on this documentation:

[React Navigation 4.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating#summary)

It will be better if you clear the asyncStorage after user clicked the logout button.

Answer (score 1):

First create TabNavigator_1 like this:-

```
const TabNavigator1 = createBottomTabNavigator({
 Home: HomeScreen,
Settings: SettingsScreen,
});
```

create second TabNavigator_2 like this:-

```
const TabNavigator2 = createBottomTabNavigator({
 Home: HomeScreen,
 Settings: SettingsScreen,
});
```

Then Stack Navigator :-

```
  const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Tab1: TabNavigator1,
  Tab2: TabNavigator2,
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Login',
}
);
```

A main Main Navigator: -

```
{this.state.isLogin ? <StackNavigator/> : <TabNavigator1/>}
```

on LogOut you can go like:-

```
onPress=()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}
```

OR

```
onPress=()=>{this.props.navigation.push('Login')}
```

Hope it help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Dispatch a `reset` action and navigate to the Login Screen:

```js
import { CommonActions } from "@react-navigation/native";

....

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [{ name: "LoginScreen" }],
  })
);
```

This avoids *undesired behavior* such as a secondary Tab remaining selected.